# How to set height and width of background image inline style in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

can someone please help me out with this ?

I have this problem: I am fetching an image from api and I want to set it as background (FULL-SCREEN background), somehow it doesn´t work for me when I want to set 100% height and width and other stylings to that image as inline styling. How am I supposed to do that ?

Or is it possible to fetch an image and somehow use it in css as background-image: ... ?

I am fetching an image from django back end.

```
render() {
        return (
        <section style={{backgroundImage: `url(${this.state.pic})`}}>
        <h3>404 Page Not Found!</h3>
        </section>
         )
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Give your section a classname.
2. Create a new CSS-styling sheet. Like "style.css" and link it to your react app.
3. Do the following

   ```
   render() {
       return (
       <section className="mySection" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${this.state.pic})`}}>

       <h3>404 Page Not Found!</h3>
       </section>
    )

   }

   //This goes in your style.css
   .mySection{
       background-position: center;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-size: cover;
       width: 100%;
       heigth: 100%;

   }
   h3{
       z-index: 99;
   }
   ```

Comment: How exactly am i suppose to put it there?

Comment: I editet my answer. I would pefer to have a seperate css-file. Much easier to customize and adjust later. Don't style directly if you don't hav eto

Comment: All it does is that it only shows the image through 1 line where is that H3 text

Comment: Editer again. Added z-index to h3 and heigth to section

Comment: when i even delete the <h3>404 Page Not Found!</h3>, there is just blank page, not even the image:/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about styling elements. This may help you!.
You can refer here! https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style

```
render() {
  return (
    <section style={{
      backgroundImage: `url(${this.state.pic})`,
      backgroundPosition: center,
      backgroundRepeat: no - repeat,
      backgroundSize: cover
    }}>
      <h3>404 Page Not Found!</h3>
    </section >
  )
}
```